# Getting 'ExceptionInInitializerError' while on with arg constructor mocking

Tags: java, testing, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I am using Junit4 for testing external java class.
I want to Mock the below line of code

```
MySearch mySearch = MyCache.getData(new MyAlgorithm(keyword.trim()), MySearch.class);
```

I tried like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyCache.class, MyAlgorithm.class})
public class Test {

@BeforeClass
  public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyCache.class);

    MyAlgorithm alg = Mockito.mock(MyAlgorithm.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(MyAlgorithm.class).withArguments("ABC").thenReturn(alg);

    MySearch mySearch = Mockito.mock(MySearch.class);
    PowerMockito.when(MyCache.getData(alg,MySearch.class)).thenReturn(mySearch);

    //...
  }
  
}
```

But still i am getting this error "**java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError**"

---

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45)
at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.ObjenesisInstantiator.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiator.java:14)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:143)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:58)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:59)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runBefores(ClassRoadie.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

Comment: Please add the full exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: Is that the whole stack trace? I would have expected a "caused by" exception after the one you've shown. Can you add the MyCache constructor to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have at least one test method. Something like:

```
@org.junit.Test
public void testMethod() {
}
```

Comment: Already have...

Comment: Your setup looks good. I would like to see the structure of your classes (constructors and methods involved in the test) in order to understand the problem. The stack trace is not very helpful so far.